# how to view table value without while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($interst_list_select_result))
```

it's work one value to many value 
I need to work without while loop but i need to all value in table.
how to i work this??

[image]

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve ..

Comment: So you want somehow to magically display every row, but without telling PHP to display every row? Why do you want this? Why can't you use a while loop? Is this a business requirement?

Comment: because it's many value show...!

Comment: Explain..... do you only want to show one row? Or d you want to show all rows but using a different method?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your database query, and explain what you actually want from that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl');
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row => $val){
    echo $val['colname1'],' ',$val['colname2'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the first result I think you can do this way

```
If( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($interst_list_select_result)){


   echo $row['you_column'];

}
```

if you need all

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row => $index){
   echo $index['you_column'];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the poster wants - `but i need to all value in table.`